# Facebook 'Like' button not working

Tags: facebook-like

My Like button is having two issues.

The first, when a person goes to my website and clicks the Like button, the count does not appear on my Facebook page.

The second, the count also doesn't appear next to the button on my web page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing that behavior.  When the page get's liked on the Facebook page, the like button on the web site also reflects this.  And the count is correctly incremented.  Also vice-verse, when liked on the web site, the page shows the like correctly. Everything seems to be OK from what I just tested.